# Showing a MKAnnotation for custom object

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation

I have a list of objects and each of those has a title, name, description, latitude, longitude and address. 
Is it possible to show this objects as MKAnnotations? I've been stuck with this for hours now. When I tried to make the objects have a CLLocationCoordinate2D I kept getting the error about latitude or longitude not being assignable.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface Oficina : NSObject <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) CLLocationCoordinate2D oficinaCoordinate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaCiudad;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaEstado;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaTitulo;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaTelefono;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaLatitud;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaLongitud;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaDireccion;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaHorario;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaTipoDeOficina;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaServicios;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaTipoDeModulo;


@end
```

So after consuming an internet service I get around 70 of these objects. Now I want to be able to turn each of those into a map annotation. 
This is one of the ways I've tried to assign the latitude but I get the error "Expression not assignable"..

```
currentOffice.oficinaCoordinate.latitude = [parseCharacters floatValue];
```

Where currentOffice is an instance of my custom object.

Comment: can you post the code for your custom object?

Comment: Its possible, I've done it before give me a second to look at my code and show you a example.

Answer (score 2):

Its possible to show title, name, description, latitude, longitude and address as MKAnnotations.

Have you tried to change the coordinate property to 'assign'?

```
@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation> 
{   
 CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
 NSString *title;
 NSString *name;
 NSString *description;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D    coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *description;
```

Comment: Oh, one more quick question. So I was able to drop all the pins in the right places... But, lets say my app zooms into the current location when it opens... Then it drops the pins. What if the closest pin is not in the range of the screen? Is it easy to re-set the range so that at least one pin is visible?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit of sample code of how i came to tackle this problem. First loading the mapView annotation array:

```
        CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
        Annotation *myAnn;

        if (!self.locationsMutableArray) self.locationsMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];

        NSMutableArray *tmpMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSDictionary *subArr in arr)
        {
                    myAnn = [[Annotation alloc] init];
                    myAnn.address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@, %@",
                                     [subArr objectForKey:@"address"],
                                     [subArr objectForKey:@"city"],
                                     [subArr objectForKey:@"state"],
                                     [subArr objectForKey:@"zip"]];
                    location.latitude = [[subArr objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
                    location.longitude = [[subArr objectForKey:@"lon"] doubleValue];
                    myAnn.coordinate = location;
                    myAnn.title = [subArr objectForKey:@"name"];
                    myAnn.subtitle = [subArr objectForKey:@"siteSpecialtyCategory"];
                    myAnn.siteType = [subArr objectForKey:@"siteType"];
                    myAnn.phoneNumber = [subArr objectForKey:@"phoneNumber"];
                    [tmpMutableArray addObject:myAnn];
         }
        [self.locationsMutableArray addObject:tmpMutableArray];

        [self.mapView addAnnotations:array];
```

All it really is, is you need to create a custom subclass of `MKAnnotationView` mine was called `Annotation`. It also has to conform to the `<MKAnnotation>` protocol and you can add them to your map view as custom annotations.

Make your `Oficina` header file start like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface Oficina : MKAnnotationView <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) CLLocationCoordinate2D oficinaCoordinate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaCiudad;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaEstado;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaTitulo;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaTelefono;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaLatitud;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaLongitud;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaDireccion;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaHorario;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaTipoDeOficina;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaServicios;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *oficinaTipoDeModulo;


@end
```

Comment: Ok so now my objects are a subclass of MKAnnotationView and conform to MKAnnotation...I was able to set the latitude and longitude for oficinaCoordinate. So now I'm stuck with 70 objects with the right information. What am I missing to be able to drop them on screen?

Comment: Are you asking how to display them on the screen when they click on your annotation?

Comment: Great! I'm glad i was able to help out :)

Comment: Hi, I'm still struggling with this map part of my app. So finally I show the MKAnnotation with a custom icon and a rightCalloutAccessoryView. Since the annotation has all the info of my stores (offices) I want to show that detail info when the user clicks on the rightCalloutAccessoryView. For some reason I don't see how to pass my object so that when the detailViewController shows up it has info put in the screen. Any ideas? I'm using mapVies:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped to respond to the click. But can't pass my custom object.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19497/discussion-between-yulz-and-chamanhm)

Answer (score 0):

The way to get the object details for the MKAnnotation that was tapped was to add:

```
id<MKAnnotation> selectedOffice = view.annotation;
```

to the delegate method

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control { }
```

in my specific case my MKAnnotation was a custom object called Oficina, so I just passed it to my new view controller like this:

```
showOfficeDetail = (Oficina *)selectedOffice;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple, just loop your objects array and create a `MKPointAnnotation` with a coordinate and in your desired format the title and subtitle. Then add those to the map via the `addAnnotation` method and pins will appear on the map.

```
for(Event *event in events){
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(event.lat, event.lon);
    MKPointAnnotation *point = [MKPointAnnotation.alloc initWithCoordinate:coordinate title:event.name subtitle:event.venue.name];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
}
```

If you aren't happy with how the default pin looks or behave then you can create a custom pin by implementing `viewForAnnotation` but you have to be careful that you support all the different kinds of annotations on the map not just the ones you created, e.g. the annotation for user's current location.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:MKPointAnnotation.class]){
        MKPinAnnotationView *view = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CustomPin"];
        if(!view) {
            // create our custom pin view
            view = [MKPinAnnotationView.alloc initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomPin"];
            view.canShowCallout = YES;
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        }else{
            // update the previously created custom pin
            view.annotation = annotation;
        }
        return view;
    }
    else if([annotation isKindOfClass:MKUserLocation.class]){
        return nil; // use the default view for user location
    }
    return nil; // use the default view for any other annotations
}
```